# Why ORB didn't give me better result than SURF?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, surf, orb

I am trying to extract features for any given image or video frame. I have read many papers and articles about point feature based object tracking. Finally, I decided to use ORB. This is because, most of the people say in their papers that ORB is better than all of the feature extracting algorithms.

When I used ORB, it didn't give me good result. Then, I decided to try SURF method. When I used SURF, it gave me very good result.

I wonder that, what is wrong with my codes. I will share with you both codes surf and orb. Please, look at my codes and comment out about my mistakes.

SURF Result

[image: SURF Result]

ORB Result

[image: ORB Result]

```py
# With SURF Detector

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Initialize parameters for Flann based matcher
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0

flann_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE,
                   table_number = 6, # 12
                   key_size = 12,     # 20
                   trees = 5,
                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2

draw_params = dict(matchesMask=None,
                   singlePointColor=None,
                   matchColor=(255, 0, 0),
                   flags=2)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img_object = cv2.imread('form1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_scene = cv2.imread('form2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

if img_object is None or img_scene is None:
    print('Could not open or find the images!')
    exit(0)

#-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector, compute the descriptors
minHessian = 400
detector = cv2.xfeatures2d_SURF.create(hessianThreshold=minHessian)
keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj = detector.detectAndCompute(img_object, None)
keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene = detector.detectAndCompute(img_scene, None)

#-- Step 2: Matching descriptor vectors with a FLANN based matcher
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})                
knn_matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_obj, descriptors_scene, 2)

#-- Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test
ratio_thresh = 0.75
good_matches = []
for m,n in knn_matches:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

#-- Draw matches
img_matches = np.empty((max(img_object.shape[0], img_scene.shape[0]), img_object.shape[1]+img_scene.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_obj, img_scene, keypoints_scene, good_matches[:10], img_matches, **draw_params)


if len(good_matches) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    obj_pts = np.float32([ keypoints_obj[good_match.queryIdx].pt for good_match in good_matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    scene_pts = np.float32([ keypoints_scene[good_match.trainIdx].pt for good_match in good_matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

H, _ =  cv2.findHomography(obj_pts, scene_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

#-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
obj_corners = np.empty((4,1,2), dtype=np.float32)

obj_corners[0,0,0] = 0
obj_corners[0,0,1] = 0
obj_corners[1,0,0] = img_object.shape[1] # img.shape[1] shows the column of the image
obj_corners[1,0,1] = 0
obj_corners[2,0,0] = img_object.shape[1]
obj_corners[2,0,1] = img_object.shape[0] # img.shape[0] shows the row of the image
obj_corners[3,0,0] = 0
obj_corners[3,0,1] = img_object.shape[0]

scene_corners = cv2.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, H)

#-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[0,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[1,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[1,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[2,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[2,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[3,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[3,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[0,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)

#-- Show detected matches
cv2.imshow('Good Matches With SURF Detector', img_matches)
cv2.imwrite('SURF_Matches.jpg', img_matches)
cv2.waitKey()
```

```py
# With ORB Detector

import cv2
import numpy as np


# Initialize parameters for Flann based matcher
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
FLANN_INDEX_LSH    = 6

flann_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                   table_number = 6, # 12
                   key_size = 12,     # 20
                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2

draw_params = dict(matchesMask=None,
                singlePointColor=None,
                matchColor=(255, 0, 0),
                flags=2)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img_object = cv2.imread('form1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_scene = cv2.imread('form2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

if img_object is None or img_scene is None:
    print('Could not open or find the images!')
    exit(0)

#-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using ORB Detector, compute the descriptors
detector = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1500)

keypoints_obj = detector.detect(img_object, None)
keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj = detector.compute(img_object, keypoints_obj)

keypoints_scene = detector.detect(img_object, None)
keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene = detector.compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene)

#-- Step 2: Matching descriptor vectors with a BF based matcher
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})
knn_matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_obj, descriptors_scene, k=2)

# Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test
ratio_thresh = 0.75
good_matches = []
for m,n in knn_matches:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

#-- Draw matches
img_matches = np.empty((max(img_object.shape[0], img_scene.shape[0]), img_object.shape[1]+img_scene.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_obj, img_scene, keypoints_scene, good_matches[:10], img_matches, **draw_params)

if len(good_matches) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    obj_pts = np.float32([ keypoints_obj[good_match.queryIdx].pt for good_match in good_matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    scene_pts = np.float32([ keypoints_scene[good_match.trainIdx].pt for good_match in good_matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

H, _ =  cv2.findHomography(obj_pts, scene_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

#-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
obj_corners = np.empty((4,1,2), dtype=np.float32)

obj_corners[0,0,0] = 0
obj_corners[0,0,1] = 0
obj_corners[1,0,0] = img_object.shape[1] # img.shape[1] shows the column of the image
obj_corners[1,0,1] = 0
obj_corners[2,0,0] = img_object.shape[1]
obj_corners[2,0,1] = img_object.shape[0] # img.shape[0] shows the row of the image
obj_corners[3,0,0] = 0
obj_corners[3,0,1] = img_object.shape[0]

scene_corners = cv2.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, H)

#-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[0,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[1,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[1,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[2,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[2,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[3,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[3,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1])),\
    (int(scene_corners[0,0,0] + img_object.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)

#-- Show detected matches
cv2.imshow('Good Matches With ORB Detector', img_matches)
cv2.imwrite('ORB_Matches.jpg', img_matches)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have got very bad result for ORB. I tested them on the same images.
How can I get very good result by using ORB, as most people say?

Comment: are you using a binary descriptor matching technique in case of ORB?

Comment: I am using binary descriptor for matching. I tried out it by using "FLANN + LSH" and "Brute Force + Hamming distance" respectively. But both of them gave me the same result.

Comment: "This is because, most of the people say in their papers that ORB is better than all of the feature extracting algorithms." Who says this? SIFT and SURF are both excellent, but patented and require licensing to use, which is why ORB was even created. As far as I'm aware, people prefer SIFT/SURF generally, but use ORB because it's free. Also, note that ORB is just a descriptor. The detector used in the ORB functions in OpenCV is the FAST corner detector.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I agree with you. I have recently found my mistake on these codes. After I changed the codes, I tried out them. ORB gave me a better result than SURF. I noticed that ORB is very useful for extracting correct features. But after extracting features by using ORB, it doesn't track the object of interest well as does SURF.

Comment: @mmtaksuu Could you share what have you changed?